# When using $state.go, is there a controller onRouteParms you can set up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 different controllers.  I go from 1 to the other by way of `$state.go`

My question is that i noticed when i go to the controller, it doesnt fire the JS again since the state is already in place.  My issue is that I need a list to refresh.

1 controller added an item to the list, and then navigated back to the list.

I didnt really see anything, but i was hoping for some sort of onRouteParams or onRoute which will fire when a state change is called.

What is the best course of action?

In the target module, the controller has a `refresh` function which would just refresh the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to hook into the `stateChangeSuccess` event. For example:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // run code to refresh list
});
```

As you can see from the params, this gives you access to both where the user is coming from and where they have arrived.

Comment: mm. ok.  ill have to see about doing that.  I think my angular controls arent using $scope though.  i use:  var self = this; and then use self for all referencing.  Though maybe I could just do something like:  `self.$on(....`